# CSS: Style a link in a class

Tags: css

I have a < div > that's styled using a class. I want to style the links that are in that .
I tried this:

```css
.categoryName  {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.categoryName a:link  {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.categoryName a:visited  {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.categoryName a:hover  {
    color: green;
}
.categoryName a:active  {
    color: green;
}
```

Thought it would work but it has no effect whatsoever. Tried to google the answer but could only find info about styling links in general, not only the ones in < div > class.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here, it does work. http://jsfiddle.net/jeffman/44X3R/

In addition to Campari's suggestion, are you sure your div tag uses `categoryName` as a class name, not an id?

Here's the HTML I used.

```
<div class="categoryName">
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that I had the < div > between the < a >. The borders appeared fine but the link was unaffected by the styling. Put the < div > around the < a > and both worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things but nothing worked for me to style a link

until, as suggested above, I added to CSS

```
#emailstyle2 a { font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color: blue; }
```

and in HTML I added div around `<a href`

```
<div id="emailstyle2"><a href="mailto:my@gmail.com">email me</a></div>
```

and it worked!

I am a newbie, feel free to remove this if it is a wrong or bad approach

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```css
.categoryName a
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If it doesn't work maybe there's some other CSS overriding it somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think so because the border in categoryName appears as expects. This is the html line:
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('category$rowName')"><div class="categoryName">$rowName</div></a> ... The line appears fully boxed in by the border but the link inside is not affected